# How to realize drag and drop on a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, touch, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm developing a simple board game. The next step is to implement the drag and drop functionality of the tokens and I wonder how I should realize that.

Currently the whole game board is drawn into a `SurfaceView`. When the user drags a token, I would like to show an half transparent token under his finger. Also the token should disappear from the game board, when it's dragged.

Right now I see two possibilities to implement this:

1. Implement everything in one single `SurfaceView`. On touch on a token, I would remove it and paint a transparent token under the finger. Everything is redrawn constantly.

   - Do I run into performance problems? Currently the canvas drawing contains about 100 drawing actions with a few shades and gradients.
2. Drawing somehow on top of the `SurfaceView`. Remove the token from the lower `SurfaceView` and draw the token under the users finger somehow on top of it.

   - I don't know how I can do this. Somewhere I've read that I shouldn't stack `SurfaceView`, because the `SurfaceView`s background is not made to be transparent.

I'm also open for further suggestions of ideas. Please don't hesitate to provide links in the comments.

My minimum API level, that I have to support, is 15.

Comment: You can have multiple SurfaceViews on top of each other by setting the Z-ordering.  See e.g. "multi-surface test" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), which has three partially-transparent SurfaceViews.  Whether or not this is more efficient than rendering everything on your existing surface depends on a bunch of different things.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If I want to use this SurfaceView 'construct' in multiple activities, should I create a fragment, which contains this two surfaces?